# How do I tell Zsh to write the current shell's history to my history file?

Tags: shell, zsh

I work in a place that has gazillions of tools which require tons of options, so I rely on my shell's history significantly. I even back it up every now and then just to make sure I don't lose useful, lengthy commands.

I just typed one of these commands and I want to make sure it's flushed to the history file, but I have a long-running job in the background and I can't type `exec zsh`. Is there something else I can do in this situation?

(Sure, I could copy and paste it into a file, but it would be more logical for there to exist a `flush-history` command.)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To write the shell history to the history file, do

```
fc -W
```

`fc` has some useful flags, see them all in `man zshbuiltins`.

You can also fully automate reading and writing the history file after each command (thus sharing your history file automatically with each running zsh) by saying `setopt -o sharehistory`. Read more history-related options in `man zshoptions`.

Comment: Documentation:
http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands

Answer (score 24):

I also just found:

```
setopt INC_APPEND_HISTORY
```

From `man zshoptions`:

```
INC_APPEND_HISTORY
   This  options  works like APPEND_HISTORY except that new history
   lines are added to the $HISTFILE incrementally (as soon as  they
   are  entered),  rather  than waiting until the shell exits.  The
   file will still be periodically re-written to trim it  when  the
   number  of  lines grows 20% beyond the value specified by $SAVE-
   HIST (see also the HIST_SAVE_BY_COPY option).
```

Answer (score 16):

And use

```
fc -R
```

to read in the history (after writing it) in an existing zsh shell.

Answer (score 2):

appen below line to ~/.zshrc, it will save 1000 entry we increase by changing value of HISTSIZE and SAVEHIST

```
HISTSIZE=1000
if (( ! EUID )); then
  HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history_root
else
  HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history
fi
SAVEHIST=1000
```